# How to re-order Angular Material Table?

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, angular-material

**Objective:** Create a table using Angular Material that can be modified using Angular Drag & Drop.

**Expected Behavior**: Table should re-order on drag-drop

**Current Behavior**: Rows are draggable, and the order of the underlying data source changes, but when the row is dropped it snaps back to its original position in the table.

See this example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/drag-drop-reorder-mattable

How can this be fixed/implemented?

(Also, I'm not sure why it's styled so poorly in Stackblitz. Any insight there would also be appreciated)

**Edit:** I found a super hacky way to get the rows to render again with the correct order, but there's no way this is the way it's expected to be implemented. I just put `t.renderRows()` to be executed after the drop event handler. See full line below

```html
<mat-table #t
  cdkDropList
  (cdkDropListDropped)="onListDrop($event); t.renderRows()" 
  [dataSource]="dataSource"
  class="mat-elevation-z8">
  ...
</mat-table>
```

**EDIT 2:**
I've done a simple refactor to use rxjs, and the first drag-drop reorder for each element works great. But when I attempt to move an element that has already been moved once, I don't get the expected behavior. Stackblitz app has been updated.

Comment: The poor styling is due to not including a theme, just add `@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';` (or any other theme) to your styles.css.

Comment: That makes sense and it resolved the styling. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are encountering [angular/material2 issue #14056](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/14056) "cdkDropList: event.previousIndex does not update on second move". A workaround of deepcloning the datasource is detailed in the issue and it's comments.

Take a look [here](https://gfycat.com/CanineYellowEuropeanpolecat) where I play with your demo after a small change to the console log (`` console.log(`Moving item[${event.previousIndex}] "${this.items[event.previousIndex]}" to index ${event.currentIndex}`) ``)

I drag "Item 0" from index 0 to index 3. The item at index 0 moves to index 3. ✔️
I drag "Item 0" from index 3 to index 1. The item at index 0 moves to index 1. ✖️
I drag "Item 0" from index 3 to index 2. The item at index 0 moves to index 2. ✖️

The `event.previousIndex` erroneously remains the same for a row after it has been moved to a different index.

Comment: This seems to work with simple data sources, but not when the mat table source is an Observable. How can the deep clone be used with an Observable?

Answer (score 3):

As you mentioned in your edit you do need to call `renderRows()` each time you modify the datasource. It is even mentioned in the Angular Material documentation [here](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTable).

> Renders rows based on the table's latest set of data, which was either
>   provided directly as an input or retrieved through an Observable
>   stream (directly or from a DataSource). Checks for differences in the
>   data since the last diff to perform only the necessary changes
>   (add/remove/move rows).
>
> If the table's data source is a DataSource or Observable, this will be
>   invoked automatically each time the provided Observable stream emits a
>   new data array. **Otherwise if your data is an array, this function will
>   need to be called to render any changes.**

What you could do to get around calling `renderRows()` each time, is to convert your datasource to an Observable and emit a new value in your `onListDrop()` function so the table updates automatically each time you drag/drop a row.

Comment: I ended up following your advice and changed the dataSource to an Observable (BehaviorSubject). But I've run into new issues. I've updated the post.